# Unable to reset .spec.finalizers on a k8s namespace, what is going on?

Tags: kubernetes

I have `.spec.finalizers` on a namespace:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k get ns linkerd-viz -o 'jsonpath={.spec.finalizers}' 2> /dev/null
["kubernetes"]mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

I send the error output to `/dev/null`, because of this:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k get ns linkerd-viz -o 'jsonpath={.spec.finalizers}' > /dev/null
E0227 20:22:40.576095   22240 memcache.go:255] couldn't get resource list for tap.linkerd.io/v1alpha1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E0227 20:22:40.597549   22240 memcache.go:106] couldn't get resource list for tap.linkerd.io/v1alpha1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E0227 20:22:40.609182   22240 memcache.go:106] couldn't get resource list for tap.linkerd.io/v1alpha1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E0227 20:22:40.620008   22240 memcache.go:106] couldn't get resource list for tap.linkerd.io/v1alpha1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

But since this question is not about it, I would like to remove it from the output.

Anyway, as you can see there is an item in the finalizers list. I am going to remove it using the following command:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k get ns linkerd-viz -o yaml 2>/dev/null | yq '.spec.finalizers=[]' | k apply -f-
E0227 20:25:37.345805   22485 memcache.go:255] couldn't get resource list for tap.linkerd.io/v1alpha1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E0227 20:25:37.363785   22485 memcache.go:106] couldn't get resource list for tap.linkerd.io/v1alpha1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
Warning: Detected changes to resource linkerd-viz which is currently being deleted.
namespace/linkerd-viz configured
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

I am 100% sure the command is correct, but the finalizers are not removed. I tried doing it in an editor with `k edit ns`, but the result is the same - the finalizers are there.

What is going on?

**EDIT 1**

There is nothing in the `linkerd-viz` namespace:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k api-resources --namespaced -o name 2>/dev/null | xargs -n1 kubectl -n linkerd-viz get 2> /dev/null
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

**EDIT 2**

There used to be a mutating webhook named `linkerd-tap-injector-webhook-confi`, but I deleted it:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k get mutatingwebhookconfigurations 2> /dev/null
NAME                               WEBHOOKS   AGE
aks-node-mutating-webhook          1          6h2m
aks-webhook-admission-controller   1          6h2m
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following command to track anything related to linkerd-viz:

```
k api-resources -o name 2> /dev/null | xargs -n1 -I{} bash -c 'echo {} ; kubectl -A --no-headers get {} 2>/dev/null | grep linker'
...
apiservices.apiregistration.k8s.io
v1alpha1.tap.linkerd.io                linkerd-viz/tap              False (ServiceNotFound)   78m
...
clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io
linkerd-linkerd-viz-metrics-api                        ClusterRole/linkerd-linkerd-viz-metrics-api                                        79m
linkerd-linkerd-viz-prometheus                         ClusterRole/linkerd-linkerd-viz-prometheus                                         79m
linkerd-linkerd-viz-tap                                ClusterRole/linkerd-linkerd-viz-tap                                                79m
linkerd-linkerd-viz-tap-auth-delegator                 ClusterRole/system:auth-delegator                                                  79m
linkerd-linkerd-viz-web-admin                          ClusterRole/linkerd-linkerd-viz-tap-admin                                          79m
linkerd-linkerd-viz-web-api                            ClusterRole/linkerd-linkerd-viz-web-api                                            79m
linkerd-linkerd-viz-web-check                          ClusterRole/linkerd-linkerd-viz-web-check                                          79m
linkerd-tap-injector                                   ClusterRole/linkerd-tap-injector                                                   79m
clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io
linkerd-linkerd-viz-metrics-api                                        2023-02-28T00:20:59Z
linkerd-linkerd-viz-prometheus                                         2023-02-28T00:20:59Z
linkerd-linkerd-viz-tap                                                2023-02-28T00:20:59Z
linkerd-linkerd-viz-tap-admin                                          2023-02-28T00:20:59Z
linkerd-linkerd-viz-web-api                                            2023-02-28T00:20:59Z
linkerd-linkerd-viz-web-check                                          2023-02-28T00:20:59Z
linkerd-tap-injector                                                   2023-02-28T00:20:59Z
rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io
kube-system         linkerd-linkerd-viz-tap-auth-reader                 Role/extension-apiserver-authentication-reader        79m
...
```

Turns out the `apiservices.apiregistration.k8s.io` instance was the culprit both for the errors and for the finalizers. Deleting it I was able to proceed:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k delete apiservices.apiregistration.k8s.io v1alpha1.tap.linkerd.io 2> /dev/null
apiservice.apiregistration.k8s.io "v1alpha1.tap.linkerd.io" deleted
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k get ns
NAME                STATUS        AGE
argocd              Terminating   123m
calico-system       Active        6h8m
default             Active        6h8m
gatekeeper-system   Active        6h8m
kube-node-lease     Active        6h8m
kube-public         Active        6h8m
kube-system         Active        6h8m
tigera-operator     Active        6h8m
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

No errors and the namespaces I tried to delete were finally deleted.